# Por qué mi rest api en NodeJS al dejar de hacerle request por unos minutos deja de funcionar

Tags: mysql, nodejs

Tengo una rest api que estoy usando para mostrar info en un front-end con AngularJS pero esta misma si por ejemplo por unos minutos no se le hacen requests al hacerle una me devuelve el error de query, tengo que reiniciar el node para que vuelva a funcionar cada vez.

Yo lo estoy iniciando con `npm start REST.js` no se si es la forma correcta.

REST.js

```js
var mysql = require("mysql");
var crypto = require('crypto');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var datetime = new Date();

function REST_ROUTER(router,connection,md5) {
    var self = this;
    self.handleRoutes(router,connection,md5);
}

REST_ROUTER.prototype.handleRoutes = function(router,connection,md5) {
    var self = this;
    router.get("/",function(req,res){
        res.json({"Message" : "Hello World !"});
    });

    //Allow CORS conections.
    router.use(function(req, res, next) {
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type, Authorization');
        next();
    });

    router.get("/users",function(req,res){
        var query = "SELECT * FROM ??";
        var table = ["cuenta"];
        query = mysql.format(query,table);
        connection.query(query,function(err,rows){
            if(err) {
                res.json({"Error" : true, "Message" : "Error executing MySQL query"});
            } else {
                res.json(rows);
            }
        });
    });

    router.get("/admins",function(req,res){
        var query = "SELECT * FROM ?? WHERE adminlvl >= 1";
        var table = ["cuenta"];
        query = mysql.format(query,table);
        connection.query(query,function(err,rows){
            if(err) {
                res.json({"Error" : true, "Message" : "Error executing MySQL query"});
            } else {
                res.json(rows);
            }
        });
    });

    router.get("/login/:name/:password",function(req,res){
        var query = "SELECT * FROM ?? WHERE nombre = ? AND pass = ?";
        var table = ["cuenta", req.params.name, crypto.createHash('md5').update(req.params.password).digest("hex")];
        query = mysql.format(query,table);
        connection.query(query,function(err,rows){
            if(err) {
                res.json({"Error" : true, "Message" : "Error executing MySQL query"});
            } 
            if (Object.keys(rows).length === 0) {
                res.json({"login" : false, "Message" : "Usuario y/o contraseña incorrectos"});
            }else {
                var token = jwt.sign({ foo: 'bar' }, 'shhhhh');
                res.json({login: true, token: token});
            }
        });
    });

    router.get("/new",function(req,res){
        var query = "SELECT * FROM ?? WHERE ?? LIKE ?";
        var table = ["cuenta", "fecha", "%"+datetime.getFullYear()+"%"];
        query = mysql.format(query,table);
        connection.query(query,function(err,rows){
            if(err) {
                res.json({"Error" : true, "Message" : "Error executing MySQL query"});
            } else {
                res.json({users: rows.length});
            }
        });
    });


    router.get("/names",function(req,res){
        var query = "SELECT nombre FROM ??";
        var table = ["cuenta",];
        query = mysql.format(query,table);
        connection.query(query,function(err,rows){
            if(err) {
                res.json({"Error" : true, "Message" : "Error executing MySQL query"});
            } else {
                res.json(rows);
            }
        });
    });

    router.get("/users/:user_id",function(req,res){
        var query = "SELECT * FROM ?? WHERE ??=?";
        var table = ["cuenta","id",req.params.user_id];
        query = mysql.format(query,table);
        connection.query(query,function(err,rows){
            if(err) {
                res.json({"Error" : true, "Message" : "Error executing MySQL query"});
            } else {
                res.json(rows);
            }
        });
    });
   

   router.get("/users",function(req,res){
        var query = "INSERT INTO ??(??,??) VALUES (?,?)";
        var table = ["cuenta","email","pass",req.body.email,md5(req.body.password)];
        query = mysql.format(query,table);
        connection.query(query,function(err,rows){
            if(err) {
                res.json({"Error" : true, "Message" : "Error executing MySQL query"});
            } else {
                res.json({"Error" : false, "Message" : "User Added !"});
            }
        });
    });


module.exports = REST_ROUTER;
```

Server.js

```js
var express = require("express");
var mysql   = require("mysql");
var bodyParser  = require("body-parser");
var md5 = require('MD5');
var rest = require("./REST.js");
var app  = express();

function REST(){
    var self = this;
    self.connectMysql();
};

REST.prototype.connectMysql = function() {
    var self = this;
    var pool      =    mysql.createPool({
        connectionLimit : 1000,
        host     : 'xxxx',
        user     : 'xxxx',
        password : 'xxxx',
        database : 'xxxx',
        debug    :  false
    });
    pool.getConnection(function(err,connection){
        if(err) {
          self.stop(err);
        } else {
          self.configureExpress(connection);
        }
    });
}

REST.prototype.configureExpress = function(connection) {
      var self = this;
      app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
      app.use(bodyParser.json());
      var router = express.Router();
      app.use('/api', router);
      var rest_router = new rest(router,connection,md5);
      self.startServer();
}

REST.prototype.startServer = function() {
      app.listen(80,function(){
          console.log("El servidor esta escuchando el puerto 80.");
      });
}

REST.prototype.stop = function(err) {
    console.log("PROBLEMA CON MYSQL " + err);
    process.exit(1);
}

new REST();
```

Y al pasar unos minutos sin requests, me devuelve el error que tengo seteado `{"Error" : true, "Message" : "Error executing MySQL query"}`

Comment: donde tienes tu db?? local o remota

Comment: Remota, en un web hosting

Comment: me late que tu web hosting es free por lo tanto pasado un tiempo la web se duerme, por lo cual rechaza la conexión y solo luego de intentar y que te rechaze lo vuelve a tomar. Prueba local y averigua las caracteristicas del hosting. Si ésta respuesta te sirve avisame asi la pongo como respuesta y la cierras, Saludos

Comment: Intenta personalizar el mensaje de error en cada uno de los `endpoints` y agregar `err`. De esa forma podrás identificar cual de todos esta dando error y por que. Ejemplo: `res.json({"Error" : true, "Message" : "Error executing MySQL query at /names", "err": err});`

Answer (score 1):

Podrías intentar verificar si esta activa la conexión, si no, vuelves a conectar y ejecutar el query.

```
     if(connection){
          connection.query(query,function(err,rows){
               if(err) {
                   res.json({"Error" : true, "Message" : "Error executing MySQL query"});
               } else {
                   res.json(rows);
               }
          });
     }else{
          //vuelves a conectar y ejecutar query
     }
```

Comment: Esto no funciona :(

Comment: @Santiago funciona si tienes algo parecido a esto... connection = mysql.createConnection({
               host : 'localhost',
               user : 'nuestroUsuarioDeMySQL',
               password : 'nuestraContraseñaDeMySQL',
               database: 'nombreBD'
         });

Comment: Arriba puse en el contenido del Server.js esta mi codigo de conexion

Answer (score 1):

Descubri que el problema esta en el VPS y no en el codigo, Gracias.